# Are Spring Security RememberMe tokens case-sensitive?

Tags: spring-security

Generating my Spring Security 4.0.1 RememberMe token I discovered that this token generating code failed on the token decode:

```
  MessageDigest md5Digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
  String md5String = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(md5Digest.digest((emailAddress + ":" + expiryTime + ":" + password + ":" + key).getBytes()));
  String token = emailAddress + ":" + expiryTime + ":" + md5String;
  Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
  String encodedToken = encoder.encodeToString(token.getBytes());
```

But that this code succeeded:

```
  String md5String = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(md5Digest.digest((emailAddress + ":" + expiryTime + ":" + password + ":" + key).getBytes())).toLowerCase();
```

The token decoder expected the MD5 string in lowercase even though the generated MD5 string was upper.

This is the md5String as originally generated (before the `toLower()`):

```
testLogin: md5String: E34B931F1F6C02C344AB28A8103F6D23
```

And this is the error message that shows the lowercase expectation:

```
Invalid remember-me cookie: Cookie token[2] contained signature 'E34B931F1F6C02C344AB28A8103F6D23' but expected 'e34b931f1f6c02c344ab28a8103f6d23'
```

(I have an `extractRememberMeCookie` override that fakes out the cookie from the header)

Is there a better way to do this that doesn't include the `toLower()` hack?

Comment: Where md5String is used then in your code? Is it used to be compared with the same token in db?

Comment: The md5String lives in the token, the request/response header, and the SecurityContext, it isn't persisted

Comment: Is that possible that when you generate signature you use toLower()? You are doing something wrong... Look here for an example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.java

Comment: Ah, thanks, the culprit is Hex.encode, it uses all lowercase chars. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/codec/Hex.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was Hex.encode, it uses all lowercase chars.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/codec/Hex.java